# How to bind two database fields into a dropdown list

Tags: asp.net

I'm having dropdown  list and two radio buttons in my web application. I need to bind two fields(code, name) from database to the dropdown list. When I change the selected value of the drop down list, according to the selected value(code) it should enable relevant radio button.

can any one let me know how to bind two database fields to a dropdown list.
Thanks.

Comment: enable autopost for dropdown's and on change event fill second dropdownlist and on change of second select dropdown...

Comment: http://oops-solution.blogspot.in/2011/10/step1-creating-table-in-database.html go throgh this article you will find all things you need

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("CODE");
            dt.Columns.Add("NAME");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "1";
            dr[0] = "NAME 1";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "2";
            dr[0] = "NAME 2";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "3";
            dr[0] = "NAME 3";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


            dlList.DataSource = dt;
            dlList.DataTextField = "NAME";
            dlList.DataValueField = "CODE";

            dlList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about Linq-to-SQL. its a very powerful tool which converts your database tables into classes. Then you can easily update your dropdownlist and toggle between radio buttons.